# gnuplot 4.6 package issue: short of x11 and gif terminal

Tags: gnuplot, x11, gif

I download the gnuplot 4.6 package from:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/4.6.0/
But I find it doesn't contain x11 and gif terminal,which is needed for my coding. 
the download link is from gnuplot homepage.
so how to install the x11 and gif package for linux system? or Where I can get a gnuplot package with such subpackage?

Comment: For Linux only the sources are provided, so you must compile gnuplot properly to contain all the terminals you need. Or you use the packaging system of your distribution to install gnuplot.

Answer (score -1):

As the comment already says, you'll usually find gnuplot in the package manager of your distribution.

One pitfall observed with Ubuntu: There are two packages, gnuplot and gnuplot-x11. Guess which one you want ;-)

If compiling gnuplot from source, you need to have the libraries *and their header files* for gif / x11 / whatever already installed, but also they can be installed via your package manager.